# Finding global functions in PHP

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to refactor a rather big project (over 100k lines of code) which has a mix of functions, methods and static methods. I need help finding all functions which are not declared within a class scope so I can move them to one. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php and/or have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

You can easily debug the project and get meta-information about existing functions by calling:

```
$array = get_defined_functions();
$array = $array['user'];
print_r($array);
```

PHP 5.4.0 (and newer)

```
print_r(get_defined_functions()['user']);
```

Comment: Bear in mind that PHP only knows about functions defined in included files. Depending on your project, you might need to `include` all relevant files before calling `get_defined_functions()`

Comment: This will help, but it won't solve my problem as some functions are declared within if-statements and in files which are only included on specific pages. Yes, I'm fixing some really broken code.

Comment: @AmusableLemur If so: delete the project, leave your job, do something else. You will loose years of your live as well as energy.